# Unable to export or edit XY data using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, xy

I am using ArcMap.

I have a polygon shapefile. I added columns for the x and y of the centroid of each polygon using the Add Geometry Attributes tool. I then used the Make XY Event Layer tool to create a new point file of the centroid x,y coordinates. I also didn't need all of the records in that file so I selected the ones I needed and then used Create Layer from Selected Features.

I basically can't do anything further with this file and I don't know why. I realized there was a point that I could delete from my selected layer but I am unable to delete it. I need to move some of the points to make the map look better but keep getting an error that this layer is not editable. I thought maybe I needed to export it to a new shapefile, but when I try that, I get the following errors:

> Error exporting data.  The Fields collection contained multiple
> geometry fields.  The table was not found. (this line six times)

My layer has 41 records. There are no null values. There are no weird characters in the column names. I am attempting to export to the same default geodatabase that I export everything to. I get the same result whether I choose to use the same coordinate system as the source layer or the data frame.

How do I export and/or edit this file?

Comment: Use copy features on xy event layer to create separate point feature class.

Comment: Yay that worked! Thank you!